# Error while executing make check on glibc build for LFS

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compilation, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I try to build my own Linux from scratch -yeah yeah from https://www.fr.linuxfromscratch.org/ . (Warning here : it's the french page I show you here) I am at this page https://www.fr.linuxfromscratch.org/view/lfs-stable/chapter08/glibc.html, trying to do the make check. I got an error on that step. The end of what is print at output is this:

```
UNSUPPORTED: misc/tst-pkey
UNSUPPORTED: posix/bug-ga2-mem
UNSUPPORTED: posix/tst-cet-vfork-1
FAIL: posix/tst-vfork3
UNSUPPORTED: posix/tst-vfork3-mem
...
Summary of test results:
      1 FAIL
   5162 PASS
     87 UNSUPPORTED
     18 XFAIL
      4 XPASS
make[1]: *** [Makefile:660 : tests] Erreur 1
make[1]: La cible « check » n'a pas été refabriquée à cause d'erreurs.
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.38 »
make: *** [Makefile:9 : check] Erreur 2
```

I highlight here the line "FAIL: posix/tst-vfork3"; is this a critical error? That is my big question.

Thanks in advance

Note : I can output a log if necessary. Just tell me which log to send.

I try to compile Linux from scratch, part 8.5 glibc-2.38. I want to ensure make check is okay before to go on.

Comment: In file /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.38/build/posix/tst-vfork3.out, I saw that message : error: tst-vfork3.c:151: could not create temporary directory. It looks like the test cannot create a directory. That causes the error.

Comment: I went also in that file : /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.38/build/posix/tst-vfork3-mem.test-result. I saw the message UNSUPPORTED: posix/tst-vfork3-mem
original exit status 77